# Laravel Eloquent - Update() function always return true

Tags: laravel, sql-update, eloquent

Consider the code

```
return User::find($user_id)->update($data_array)?true:false;
```

if `$data_array` have some columns that are not present in User related table.
then also above statement `return true`.

e.g: `$data_array=['not_in_the_table'=>'value'];`

```
return User::find($user_id)->update($data_array)?true:false;
```

returns true. What is the condition when update returns `0` i.e. `false`?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `where('id','=',$user_id)` like below  instead of `find($id)`, you will get error  like `Column not found` for the columns that are not present in User related table. So it is best way to do this :

```
User::where('id','=',$user_id)->update(['column_name'=>'value']);
```

Instead of :

```
User::find($user_id)->update($data_array)?true:false;
```

Update method always return int. For more info [Check Here](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_update)

or If you want to update the the record by using [Object Relation Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)  way then you can do like this :

```
 $user = User::find($user_id) ;
 $user->column_name = 'value';
 if($user->save()){
         //do something when user is update 
 }else{
         // do something wehn user is not update
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get error into false there because validation of Laravel use library.

For Laravel 4.2

```
public function update($user_id) {
  $data_array = Input::all();
  $validator = Validator::make(
    $data_array,
    array('name' => 'required|min:5')
  );

  if ($validator->passes()) {
    // success as true
    User::find($user_id)->update($data_array)
  } else {
    //failed as false
  }
}
```

For more information about [validator](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation)
I hope this help you